# Interesting result with forgotten '[3]' in array

Tags: java, arrays

I accidentally didn't type three characters in my code, and I fixed it easily, but the result I got was interesting.

Code:

```
class AutoArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] month_days = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 30};

        System.out.println("April has " + month_days + " days.");
    }
}
```

Result:

```
April has [I@7344699f days.
```

What does `[I@7344699f` mean? Is this some sort of identifier VS uses to identify the list in its code? Something else?

Comment: This is the result of calling `toString` on an `int[]`.

Comment: Why do you think VS is involved at all?  That's just what you get if you convert an int array to string -- It's an encoding of the hex address of the array.

Comment: `System.out.printf("April has %d days%n", Month.APRIL.length(false));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`month_days` is an array of integers. When you concatenate it with a string Java will use the toString() method to return a string that can actually be concatenated. That string will be an internal identifier of the array. That's the expected result. If you want to print the array in a readable way you have to use other methods. Just search for those.

When you add an index it returns an integer so the toString() method will return an string representation of the same number.

If by VS you mean Visual Studio Code, it has nothing to do with the execution of the program. It is just an IDE. It executes Java commands to compile and execute the program. It is the Java JVM that actually executes the code.